# qsort - What goes on behind the scenes?

Tags: c, arrays, qsort

Using this simple sample, there are 6 numbers currently ordered 5,4,3,2,1,0 and will be sorted as : 0,1,2,3,4,5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = {5,4,3,2,1,0};
int sizeOfArray = sizeof(values)/sizeof(int);

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) 
{
    printf("Comparing %d and %d \n",*(int*)a, *(int*)b);
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main () {
   int n;
   printf("Size of Array : %d\n", sizeOfArray);
   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < sizeOfArray; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   printf("\n");

   qsort(values, sizeOfArray, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < sizeOfArray; n++ ) {   
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Added to the cmpfunc function is a printf command to show the numbers being compared as each function is called.

```
Size of Array : 6
Before sorting the list is: 
5 4 3 2 1 0 
Comparing 4 and 3 
Comparing 5 and 3 
Comparing 5 and 4 
Comparing 1 and 0 
Comparing 2 and 0 
Comparing 2 and 1 
Comparing 3 and 0 
Comparing 3 and 1 
Comparing 3 and 2 

After sorting the list is: 
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Notice the application only calls the cmpfunc 9 times. 
I would have expected this function to be called numerous times more. 
Also notice that 5 or 4 is never compared to 2 or to 1.

Is anyone able to explain what is going on behind the scenes which causes this routine to be so efficient?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort ?

Comment: Read about how *quick sort* algorithm works. *I would have expected...* - if you have some expectations, you should justify them.

Comment: Just Google quick sort

Comment: "Also notice that 5 or 4 is never compared to 2 or to 1." But 5 is compared to 4, and 4 is compared to 3, and 3 is compared to both 2 and to 1. Ordering satisfies [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), so those comparisons give enough information to know that `5 > 1` (for example).

Comment: Note that `qsort()` is not specified to use the Quicksort algorithm.

Comment: @chux Surprisingly it isn't... Yet in practice (looking in the stdlib source code now...) that is how it is usually implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the "QuickSort" reference as I was unaware that was the name associated with the functionality.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is a bit surprising, but in line with broad coding goals: - get the job done, how well is a matter of quality.  IAC, worst case, is _likely_ O(n * log(n))

Comment: @chux I agree. The only source for the surprise is the `q` letter in the name :)

Comment: That's interesting how this question is getting voted.

Comment: Somebody should write a book about this. And about searching too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Too subtle, I suspect. (For anyone who's wondering: https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201896850)

Answer (score 1):

After researching "QuckSort" it makes a lot more sense. 
I modified the example to add an extra print statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 5,4,3,2,1,0};
int sizeOfArray = sizeof(values)/sizeof(int);

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) 
{
    int n = 0;
   printf("Comparing %d and %d  current array looks like this :" ,*(int*)a, *(int*)b);
   for( n = 0 ; n < sizeOfArray; n++ ) 
   {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main () {
   int n;
   printf("Size of Array : %d\n", sizeOfArray);
   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < sizeOfArray; n++ ) 
   {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   printf("\n");

   qsort(values, sizeOfArray, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < sizeOfArray; n++ ) {   
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

After reading the Wikipedia page and printing out the state of the array each time it makes sense what is going on and it matches the diagram flow.

```
Size of Array : 6
Before sorting the list is: 
5 4 3 2 1 0 
Comparing 4 and 3  current array looks like this :5 4 3 2 1 0 
Comparing 5 and 3  current array looks like this :5 3 4 2 1 0 
Comparing 5 and 4  current array looks like this :5 3 4 2 1 0 
Comparing 1 and 0  current array looks like this :3 4 5 2 1 0 
Comparing 2 and 0  current array looks like this :3 4 5 2 0 1 
Comparing 2 and 1  current array looks like this :3 4 5 2 0 1 
Comparing 3 and 0  current array looks like this :3 4 5 0 1 2 
Comparing 3 and 1  current array looks like this :3 4 5 0 1 2 
Comparing 3 and 2  current array looks like this :3 4 5 0 1 2 

After sorting the list is: 
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: For the last 3 comparisons I noticed the array has not changed its order. Shouldn't those array orders been different for the last 3 comparisons?

Comment: It's probably speeding things up by looking ahead before making a swap.  I haven't really studied the algorithm, but I think at this point it basically knows 3, 4, and 5 are in order with respect to each other, and 0, 1, and 2 are in order with respect for each other.  So now it's figuring out how those segments relate to each other.  It sees 3 is bigger than 0, but instead of moving {3,4,5} after 0, it checks against 1.  Sees that it belongs somewhere after 1, so then checks 2.  Sees it belongs after 2 and there's nothing after 2, so it's found where {3,4,5} belongs.

Comment: Since this "quicksort" is about efficiency, what you stated makes sense. Why bother making a move every time if you are searching to find when a single move can be done. Thanks.

Comment: @UnhandledException: There is no reason a comparison should result in any change of element order. Before doing a comparison, you do not know whether a change is needed or not. The comparison might tell you that a change is needed, or it might tell you a change is not needed. If no change is needed, then no change is made. Consider what happens if you pass an already sorted array to `qsort`. Then it does not need to make any changes at all. But it cannot know that until it has done a number of comparisons.

Comment: @Eric - Based on the rule for the return value if ">0 The element pointed by p1 goes after the element pointed by p2" this was interpreted as they actually swap but re-reading and it doesn't state a swap takes place but simply makes note that p1 goes after p2 which is in line with what you posted. Thanks.